# setRangeNotifier(RangeNotifier) has been deprecated?

Tags: android, altbeacon, deprecation-warning

I am using the alt.beacon library and now I get this warning:

```
warning: [deprecation] setRangeNotifier(RangeNotifier) in BeaconManager has been deprecated.
```

But what is the replacement? I need to range the beacons from a region and the callback RangeNotifier it crucial to implement this feature.

```
public interface RangeNotifier {
    void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> var1, Region var2);
}
```

Anyone has a sample of how the new library is supposed to work?

thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with version 2.9, you may have more than one `RangeNotifier`.  So instead of calling:

```
beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
```

Simply call:

```
beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
```

Comment: It may be worth noting to call 
    beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
prior to adding it again, though it probably is common sense. I am setting the range notifier from a fragment, and this can be added to any activity that needs to monitor beacons. Without clearing the range notifiers, you end up getting a range result for every rangeNotifier you have added, which can amount to a lot when navigating around an app

Comment: The good news is that this should not be necessary. The collection of rangeNotifiers is defined as a Set:  `    protected final Set<RangeNotifier> rangeNotifiers = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();` so if you add the same notifier multiple times, it should simply replace the one that already exists.

Comment: Hmmmmm .. that doesn't seem to be the case for me. The same fragment adds itself on various activities. And I found that going from menu (with beacon detection) to activity (with beacon detection) and back again say 5 times, it would result in 5 range triggers every second! The same notifier is used as the code is unchanged, the only difference could be a getActivity reference when I'm displaying the beacon in the UI? Would this change the notifier and make it unique?

Comment: Ah, perhaps the issue is that the fragment is a different object instance each time.  In this case, clearing the old notifiers is probably the correct approach.