# Parsing Beacon Information in didEnterRegion Method of Altbeacon Library

Tags: altbeacon

I would like to use the didEnterRegion method in association with the RegionBootstrap or MonitorNotifier in my application. Currently I'm using the RegionBootstrap but perhaps the MonitorNotifier is better for my application.

In particular I'm adding an iBeacon parser to the beaconmanager and then setting "Id1" of a region to look for the UUID portion of my iBeacon and setting "Id2" and "Id3" to Null. Though they are set to Null in the Region, I would like to be able to parse the information from those locations upon entering the didEnterRegion method. I'm using "Id2" (Major) and "Id3" (Minor) to provide random identification parameters of the beacons.

This information along with a portion of the data from the UUID would then be sent in a notification to the phone user. When testing, I'm entering the didEnterRegion method but the data that is provided is only that which matches the set region of "Id1". If someone could provide any insight at all, it would be greatly appreciated!

I would also like to receive the didEnterRegion method for the same iBeacon every 10 seconds, but with testing it appeared that once that particular iBeacon was seen once, didEnterRegion wouldn't get a subsequent call again. Any way to clear that the iBeacon was captured so that subsequent captures could happen?

I'm trying to keep the battery usage as low as possible and when using the scanRecord data from a onNonBeaconLEScan to parse the information, I'm noticing significant battery drain even when setting the foreground and background time "BetweenScanPeriod" to something really large. I really only need to see that the iBeacon entered the region and pull the information, then 10 seconds later do it again.

**Intended application flow** -

- User enters region of beacon with matching UUID (ID1)
- Beacon information from ID2 and ID3 are parsed and sent along with ID1 to user via notification
- 10 seconds later user receives another notification with same data
- repeat until person leaves region or iBeacon stops transmitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get the information you need is to enable ranging in the `didDetermineStateForRegion` callback:

```
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
}

public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
  for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
     Identifier id2 = beacon.getId2();
     Identifier id3 = beacon.getId3();
     // Now do something with id2 and id3
  }
}
```

The `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback will be made every 1100 ms with default settings, but you can change this to be 10 seconds if you wish with a line like this the first time you access the BeaconManager:

```
beaconManager.setScanPeriod(10000l); 
beaconManager.setBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
```

In terms of battery, if you want to be getting scan updates every 10 seconds, you will be using a lot of battery, because this means doing almost constant bluetooth scans.  In the background, you may wish to back off and do a 10 second scan only once every 5 minutes with this:

```
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(10000l); 
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(290000l); 
BackgroundPowerSaver powerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver();
```

Comment: Thanks David! Using your suggestions and this other post on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063992/how-to-range-beacons-in-background-using-altbeacon-android-beacon-library, I was able to get my application working about 98% of the way I need it to. Something I'm noticing is that if the phone has set idle for a decent period of time that I occasionally miss a beacon transmission but, as soon as I interact with the phone, then I receive the beacon every time. Could you help me understand better, how the power saving background scanning works? Thanks! @davidgyoung

Comment: When the app is in the background, scans switch to the background scan period, so they happen less often.